# imple game lags when i release a key and quickly press another key

Tags: vba, keydown, keyup

I wanted make a classic brick game in visual basic. While coding the movement of a rectangle which hits the ball, I got a problem. The rectangle lags when releasing the key. When I press A, release it and simulteneously press D, the recatangle hangs for a moment and then goes to the right.
Here is the part of my program.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If rectangleLeft = True And RectangleShape1.Left >= Me.ClientRectangle.Left + 2 Then
        RectangleShape1.Left -= 2
    End If

    If rectangleRight = True And RectangleShape1.Right <= Me.ClientRectangle.Right - 2 Then
        RectangleShape1.Left += 2
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        rectangleRight = False
        rectangleLeft = True
    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        rectangleLeft = False
        rectangleRight = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp

    rectangleLeft = False
    rectangleRight = False

End Sub
```

End Class
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

The lag is caused by the Repeat Delay which is a BIOS/Windows feature; which is controlled via the control panel.  What you need to do is use the timer to check the status of the desired key position and process the movement when the key is in the depressed position.

Use this win32 API method in the timer loop:
    Public Declare Function GetKeyPress Lib "user32" Alias "GetAsyncKeyState" (ByVal key As Integer) As Integer

```
    Dim i As Integer = GetKeyPress(Keys.A)
```

i will be 0 when not pressed and -32768 when pressed